# How to use select now() result in another query in Python?

Tags: python, mysql

I want to use the select now() query result which is executed in Python in another query but I am unable to do so.

My code :

```
import MySQLdb 

db = MySQLdb.connect(host,username,password,databasename)

cursor = db.cursor()

cursor.execute("SELECT NOW()")

dt = cursor.fetchone()

dt = str(dt) #1

cursor2 = db.cursor()

sql2 = "SELECT pid from PRODUCTS where date between DATE_SUB(" + dt + ", INTERVAL 2 HOUR) and " + dt  #... query2

cursor2.execute(sql2)
```

How can I use the date got in #1 in the #query2. It gives me error.

I even used the DATE_FORMAT function to convert it to the same format in which the NOW() function in SQL gives the output. and then tried using it in the SQL query. But still it gives me syntax error.

Comment: *It gives me error.* - What error?

Comment: What's wrong with using `NOW()` directly in your query ? ie `"SELECT pid from PRODUCTS where date between DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 HOUR) and NOW()"`

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers : that works perfectly fine but I need to use this in another query which I have not mentioned and want to keep the time same for both the queries . Otherwise, the time would change for both the queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `%s` on that respective dates

```
sql2 = "SELECT pid from PRODUCTS where date between DATE_SUB(%s, INTERVAL 2 HOUR) and %s"

cursor2.execute(sql2,(dt,dt))
```

Answer (score 1):

MySQLdb will automagically transform MySQL datetimes into Python native `datetime.datetime` objects, and Python native `datetime.datetime` objects into MySQL-correct datetimes, so you don't have any transformation / formatting or whatever to do by yourself. All it takes is to *correctly* use the db api:

```
import MySQLdb 
db = MySQLdb.connect(host,username,password,databasename)
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT NOW()")
dt = cursor.fetchone()[0] # fetchone returns a tuple
print dt # should print a `datetime.datetime` object

# no need for a second cursor here now you have fetched results
# from your previous query
#cursor2 = db.cursor()

# **ALWAYS** use your db connector's placeholders 
sql2 = "SELECT pid from PRODUCTS where date between DATE_SUB(%s, INTERVAL 2 HOUR) and %s"

# this way your db connector will take care of proper transformation / formatting / sanitization / escaping etc
cursor.execute(sql2, (dt, dt))
```

Answer (score 0):

This link could be useful, try it out!:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-cursor-select.html
Here's what it has:

"The task is to select all employees hired in the year 1999 and print their names and hire dates to the console."

```
import datetime
import mysql.connector

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='scott', database='employees')
cursor = cnx.cursor()

query = ("SELECT first_name, last_name, hire_date FROM employees "
         "WHERE hire_date BETWEEN %s AND %s")

hire_start = datetime.date(1999, 1, 1)
hire_end = datetime.date(1999, 12, 31)

cursor.execute(query, (hire_start, hire_end))

for (first_name, last_name, hire_date) in cursor:
  print("{}, {} was hired on {:%d %b %Y}".format(
    last_name, first_name, hire_date))

cursor.close()
cnx.close()
```